# Jquery ajax POST url getting changed and bad request returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spotify

I am using a function from [Spotify Playlist Creator](https://github.com/possan/playlistcreator-example/blob/master/callback.html) in my file to send a POST request to the API to create a new playlist. The function works fine when i run the "Spotify Playlist Creator" code, with the POST request returning a response object with a new playlist id. But the same POST request returns "400 : Bad Request" when run from my code.

Other GET requests (user profile requests) are working fine (and hence i am guessng the authorization flow is successful and the access_token is valid.)

When i used the Chrome inspector, one thing that i noticed is that in the working app, the POST url is `Request URL:https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/121856107/playlists`
In my app it is `Request URL:https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/121856107/playlists?{%22name%22:%22test_playlist%22,%22public%22:false}`

Here the url has the data elements appended to it. Why is this happening? Any pointers ?

Below i have pasted the function which is behaving differently in two different sites.

Update: It appears that the POST request is somehow converted to OPTIONS. A quick search showed that this behaviour might be related to "Same origin policy". 
How do i get my function to start working?

```
function createPlaylist(username, name, callback) {
    var url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + username +
        '/playlists';
    $.ajax(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'name': name,
            'public': false
        }),
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + g_access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(r) {
            console.log('create playlist response', r);
            callback(r.id);
        },
        error: function(r) {
            callback(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you are not working on localhost, right? sometimes spotify is blocking it.

Comment: i am working on localhost.

Comment: try to test it on the server, often spotify is blocking request from localhost.

Comment: I have updated the question. It looks like the POST request is being changed to OPTIONS. "Same origin policy". How do i get past this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: Don't use `JSON.stringify` at all.

Comment: Before making the POST request, the browser sends a preflight request through an OPTIONS to check CORS restrictions. However, that should work since the Spotify API allowed requests from every site.